# how can i retrieve username from another collection by using join in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1

```
//viewing tickets generated by them
        $user= Auth::user()->_id;
        $tickets = ticket::where(function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('user', '=', $user);
        })->get();


  //  created ticket by which user
    $atickets = ticket::where(function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_assigned', '=', $user);
    })->get();


    return view('ticketviews', compact('tickets','atickets'));
```

$atickets returns record details such as user_id and ticket details, now i need to display the username for that particular record stored in another collection mongodb. Can anyone suggest me the code to do that.

[image]

Comment: use just `$atickets = ticket::where('user_assigned', $user)->get()`

Comment: i want to display the username instead of user_id that is stored in user table. How can i do that

Comment: I don't think you can perform joins or anything similar in mongodb. 
But if you were using SQL this is how you would generally do it: 
$atickets = ticket::join('users', 'tickets.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->get()
This is assuming your tables are 'tickets' and 'users' and tickets table has 'user_id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ATIKON, its working i changed the code to

$user= Auth::user()->_id;
        $tickets = ticket::where('user', '=', $user)->get();

```
    foreach($tickets as $t){
        $use = $t->user;
        $us = User::where('_id', '=', $use)->get();
        foreach($us as $a)
        {
            $username=$a->name;
            $t['name']=$username;
        }
    }
    foreach($tickets as $t) {
        $use1 = $t->user_assigned;
        $us1 = User::where('_id', '=', $use1)->get();
        foreach ($us1 as $a1) {
            $username1 = $a1->name;
            $t['namea'] = $username1;
        }
    }
```

thanks alot for helping out

Answer (score 0):

Create relation in your model
Insert this to your ticket model

`public function user(){
 return $this->hasOne('PATH_TO_USER_MODEL', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}`

After that you can access to user data, like:

`$tickets = ticket::where('user_assigned', Auth::user()->_id)->with('user')->get();`

After you can access to your user data like `$tickets->user->name`

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user

Comment: @LeoImmanuel Did you add `user` relation function on your model?

Comment: Yes @ATIKON public function User(){
        return $this->hasOne('\App\User', 'user_assigned', '_id');
    }

Comment: $tickets = ticket::where('user_assigned', Auth::user()->_id)->with('user')->get();  @ATIKON   ticket is the model name in the above query

Comment: "subject" => "tech error"
        "user" => "5836b822cec4660e9c004815"
        "message" => "too complex"
        "priority" => "Low"
        "category" => "Tech"
        "closing_date" => null
        "solution" => "new answer"
        "user_assigned" => "5837c626cec466119c0078c4"
        "status" => "open"

Comment: @LeoImmanuel man, your `_id` is equal to your `user_assigned` or not? And rename the relation method to `users`, it might help. And access to `$tickets->users->name`